# Can't setState() in a custom handler (added CodeSandBox for demo)

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I followed an instruction https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/pen/gmroPj?editors=0010 to create a custom toolbar and handler, it works, but I would like to change a state of a variable with the handler, so I make a change of the code. Below is the code. And here is the CodeSandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-multiple-editor-gttvm

```
const FormikQuill = ({
  id,
  name,
  value,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
}) => {
  const quillRef = React.useRef();

  const [previewOpen, setPreviewOpen] = useState(false);
  const [previewContent, setPreviewContent] = useState('');

  const CustomToolbar = () => (
    <div id={`toolbar-${id}`}>
      <button className="ql-bold" />
      <button className="ql-italic" />
      <button className="ql-underline" />
      <button className="ql-strike" />
      <button className="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
      <button className="ql-script" value="super"></button>
      <select className="ql-size" defaultValue={""} onChange={e => e.persist()}>
        {['small', 'false', 'large', 'huge'].map((value, i) => (
          <option key={value} value={value} />
        ))}
      </select>
      <select className="ql-header" defaultValue={""} onChange={e => e.persist()}>
        {['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'false'].map((value) => (
          <option key={value} value={value} />
        ))}
      </select>
      <button className="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button className="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
      <button className="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
      <button className="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
      <select className="ql-color">
      </select>
      <select className="ql-background">
      </select>
      <select className="ql-align">
      </select>
      <button className="ql-link" />
      <button className="ql-clean" />
      <button className="ql-preview" value="preview">
        <VisibilityIcon />
      </button>
    </div>
  );

  const handleChange = (val, delta, source, editor) => {
    onChange(name, val);
    if(previewOpen){
      setPreviewContent(editor.getText());
    }
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    onBlur(name, true);
  };


  const quillModules = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      {
        toolbar: {
          container: `#toolbar-${id}`,
          handlers: {
            preview: function(value){ 
              const html = this.quill.root.innerHTML;
              setPreviewContent(html);
              setPreviewOpen(!previewOpen);
            }
          }
        },
      }
    )
  }, [id, previewOpen])

  const quillFormats = [
    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike',
    'script', 'size', 'header',
    'list', 'indent',
    'link', 'color', 'background', 'align'
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-editor">
        {CustomToolbar(id)}
        <ReactQuill
          ref={quillRef}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
          theme="snow"
          defaultValue={value}
          onChange={(e, delta, source, editor) => {
            handleChange(e, delta, source, editor);
          }}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          modules={quillModules}
          formats={quillFormats}
        />
        {previewOpen? <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: previewContent }} />: ''}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I add a button called `ql-preview` in the custom toolbar, I also add a handler `preview` in the `quillModules` which is the module for ReactQuill. The initial value of the state `previewOpen` is false. To avoid infinity loop, `useMemo` for the `quillModules`. The result is that, when I click the button `ql-preview`, the state of `previewOpen` is changed to true, but when I click the button again, the state of `previewOpen` is still true. No matter how many times I click the button, the state of `previewOpen` isn't changed.

ReactQuill version
v2.0.0-beta.2